# When can I append rows to a Google Sheet on upload?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, upload

I am unable to append rows to a Google Sheet when I upload an Excel (.xlsx) file. What are the conditions to make it work?

[image]

Comment: Does the file you are uploading contain multiple sheets?

Comment: It contains a single sheet. I suspect this only works for CSV.

Comment: It's possible that the importing algorithm bases the options just on the file type, before looking into it further. A CSV is guaranteed to have one sheet, so all of the options makes sense. For XLS, the last three are not certain.

Answer (score 1):

If you upload/drag-n-drop an XLSX file to Google Drive, you should be able to edit that Sheet immediately provided you convert it to Google Sheets format. I don't believe that if you preserve the Microsoft format, that you can edit an XLSX file saved to Drive.

From your screenshot, it looks like you're in the Sheets app and *importing* an XLSX -- if that radiobutton stays at "create new spreadsheet," it will create a brand new Sheets file in your Google Drive for which you should be able to edit immediately.

I just tried both techniques (both single & multiple sheet spreadsheets), and both are WaI (working-as-intended). If you provide an error, or screenshot of an error while appending rows and its failure, then perhaps we can help out more.